# Integrating the same volume with respect to different variables

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

For the following problem:

Let $R$ be the region enclosed by $y=4\sqrt{9-x}$ and the axes in the first quadrant. Region $R$ is the base of a solid. For each $y$-value, the cross-section of the solid taken perpendicular to the $y$-axis is a rectangle whose base lies in $R$ and whose height is $y$. Express the volume of the solid with a definite integral.

I get that the definite integral is $$\int\limits_0^{12}y \left( 9-\frac{y^2}{16} \right)\ dy$$ which yields 324, but then I thought why can't I get the same result by integrating with respect to $x$? So I got:
$$\int\limits_0^9 x \left( 4\sqrt{9-x} \right)\ dx$$ but that yielded 259.2. Not the same. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic region:

[image]

$$V = \int\limits_{x=0}^9 \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{9-x}} \int\limits_{z=0}^y 1 dx\ dy\ dz = \int\limits_{y=0}^3 \int\limits_{x=0}^{y^2-9} \int\limits_{z=0}^ y 1\ dy\ dx\ dz = \frac{81}{4}$$

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: but this is volume by cross sections, not rotation; the solid in question is made from rectangles

Comment: thank you for this visualization! but i don't understand why those two integrals don't both produce the one where that rectangle is the cross-section. what am i missing, if a = b and c = d, why can't i write the product as either ac or bd? is it because if i go along the x-axis, that fundamentally means my sections will be perpendicular to x-axis and not y-axis?

Comment: Now that's an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=4\sqrt{9-x}$, this implies $dy=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{9-x}}dx$. The equivalent integral would be
\begin{align*}
&\int_9^0 4\sqrt{9-x}\left(9-\frac{16(9-x)}{16}\right)\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{9-x}}\right)dx \\ &= 8\int_0^9 9-\frac{16(9-x)}{16} dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: why do i have to put the x equivalent of dy in at all, if i was just starting from the point of view of writing the whole integral with respect to x?

Comment: I think I see what you are confused about. The exercise is finding the volume of a solid with base perpendicular to the $y$ axis (which is $x$). The height happens to be $y$.

If you took the same region and asked for the volume of the object with height $x$ and base $y$, you would be correct. They don't match because they are different objects, therefore different volumes.

Comment: @user53 What it means is that the cross section in the other direction is not a rectangle anymore

Comment: but rectangle perpendicular to y-axis has base which can be written as x or as 9-(y^2/16), and height which can be written as 4sqrt(9-x) or as y, and if I run x from 0 to 9, that gives me the y-values that range from 0 to 12. so that's why i'm confused